# How can I make that X-axis label read vertically?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to customize my charts in reports (using *JasperReports* and *iReport 4.5.0*). I am using below code change Y-axis vertically but I want to write the value on X Axis vertically not the Y Axis.

```
NumberAxis leftNumberAxis = (NumberAxis) catPlot.getRangeAxis();
leftNumberAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
```

How can I make that X-axis label read vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below lines of code:

```
HorizontalCategoryAxis axis = (HorizontalCategoryAxis) catPlot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response.i am fixed that problem.The correct code is... CategoryAxis domainAxis = ((CategoryPlot) plot).getDomainAxis();       domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 2.0));